# Android Passing Variables to another activity with # not working as expected

Tags: android, regex

Ok I'm trying to create a link to an activity and it works. However passint it a variable isn't working with # charters:

```
        String hashTagString = tempValues.getDescription().replaceAll("[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\b", "<a href=\"sherif-activity://myactivity?tag=$0\">$0</a>");

        Log.i(Utils.TAG, "hashTagString: " + hashTagString);
```

The launched activity:

```
    String tag = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("tag");
    Log.i(Utils.TAG, "tag: " + tag);
```

Log Cat:

```
02-24 13:12:04.293: I/PROJECTCARUSO(29591): hashTagString: Everyone  loves <a href="sherif-activity://myactivity?tag=#hashtags">#hashtags</a> ! Take advantage of them by using them and clicking to search by them.
```

The activity it launches show this:

```
02-24 13:13:48.885: I/PROJECTCARUSO(29591): tag:
```

However if I set it with hard coded values it shows:

```
02-24 13:14:41.176: I/PROJECTCARUSO(29883): hashTagString: Everyone  loves <a href="sherif-activity://myactivity?tag=test">#hashtags</a> ! Take advantage of them by using them and clicking to search by them.
02-24 13:14:41.637: I/PROJECTCARUSO(29883): tag: test
```

I'd like to pass the whole value, but if i cannot how can I remove all special charaters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your regex is being evaluated correctlyTry using the following regex

```
\\#[A-Za-z0-9\\-_]+
```

You may need to double escape (\). The \b (word-boundary) at the end of your sequence isn't needed because it will break when it reaches a " anyway and the - in your character class needs escaping otherwise the regex is trying to evaluate a nonsense range instead of treating it as a char

**Edit**

Now you've clarified your issue the issue with getting a blank tagis this:

```
 String tag = getIntent().getData().getQueryParameter("tag");
```

It should be

```
 String tag = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tag");
```

and should be sent as

```
 new Intent(...).putExtra("tag", hashTagString);
```

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ) When i replace my regex with yours

Comment: the log says `<a href="sherif-activity://myactivity?tag=#hashtags&id=39 ">#hashtags</a>` so why would you think its not evaluating it correctly?

Comment: did you double escape them like I said?

Comment: Actually I don't think you even need to escape the #

Comment: I think your missing the question... The regex works. Passing it to the next activity as a variable doesn't. I may need to trim off the '#' from the $0 in order to get a text only but i'm not sure. Does that make since?

Comment: seeing as you have commented the same on both answers, don't you think its your wording of the question thats the problem? Try updating it and you might get *whatever* answer you are looking for.. also why didn't you say that in your first comment?

Answer (score 0):

Try `(\s|\A)#(\w+)` that as a Java string is `"(\\s|\\A)#(\\w+)"`.

You can test it in the following site: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: I think your missing the question... The regex works. Passing it to the next activity as a variable doesn't. I may need to trim off the '#' from the $0 in order to get a text only but i'm not sure. Does that make since?